# Matlab - Retrieve values from a column(col1) that does not exist in another column (col2)

Tags: matlab

How can I retrieve values ​​from a column(col1) that does not exist in another column (col2)?

```
col1 = {'C1'; 'D1'; 'H1'; 'L1'; 'M1'}

col2 = {'A1'; 'B1' ; 'C1'; 'D1'; 'E1'}
```

I can not obtain this result:

```
'H1'
'L1'
'M1'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html):

```
col1 = {'C1'; 'D1'; 'H1'; 'L1'; 'M1'}

col2 = {'A1'; 'B1' ; 'C1'; 'D1'; 'E1'}

setdiff(col1, col2)
```

This results in

```
ans = 
    'H1'
    'L1'
    'M1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Or `ismember`:

```
>> col1(~ismember(col1,col2))
ans = 
    'H1'
    'L1'
    'M1'
```